# jQuery, select nearest sibling with attribute (next or previous)

Tags: jquery, select

I have a select dropdown similar to the markup below.

```
<select class="myselect" name="myname">
  <option value="0" disabled="disabled">0</option>
  <option value="1" disabled="disabled">1</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">7</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use jQuery to select the closest "enabled" sibling to the "selected" element.  In the above example, I would like to select option 6.  I realize that I can user .prev(), but that only goes up.  Sometimes the user has a lower number selected and I need to select the next() option.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: why not use next()? are you beggining the traversal at "#selected"?

Comment: you may use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Thanks, if I start at option 0, then next(':enabled') works, but I won't if I start at option 7.  For closest(':enabled'), it goes up the  DOM, not across siblings.

Comment: @QuickSilver No, `closest` selects the closest parent element.

Comment: `closest` is misleadingly named, and it checks the parents + itself.

Comment: how about siblings( ":enabled" ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `nextAll` or `prevAll` method, you can check the *length* of the selected element, if the next *not disabled* element exists select that element otherwise select the closest previous *not disabled*  element.

```
var $o = $('.myselect option'),
    $s = $o.filter(':selected'),
    $next = $s.nextAll(':not(:disabled)').first();

if ($next.length) $next.foo();
else $s.prevAll(':not(:disabled)').first().bar();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DsWh6/

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use in the event function:

```
if( $( this ).val( ) == 7 ){

    $( enabledNode ) = $( this ).parent( ).first( ); // which brings you to val 1

    ... validation here

}
```