# How to use $(this) and closest() to form the variable passed through to jScrollPane's scrollToElement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I am wanting to scroll to the closest instance of a div using jScrollPane's `scrollToElement`([API link](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html)).

I was trying to use jQuery's `$(this)` and `closest()` to form the variable that would be passed through to `scrollToElement`.

But I think either my implementation of `$(this)` is incorrect or such a variable is not an acceptable parameter type as it's not triggering the scroll action.

The error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

How do I use `$(this)` and `closest()` to form the variable passed through to `scrollToElement`?

**jsFiddle**

Includes example of working and non-working parameters:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/bUbm8/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_content">
    <div class="click_me">CLICK ME</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <a class="target">target</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function initScrollPane(){
    var jScrollPaneSettings = {
        hijackInternalLinks: true,
        animateScroll: true,
        animateDuration: 600,
        contentWidth: '0px'
    };
    var mainContent = $('#main_content')
    mainContent.jScrollPane(jScrollPaneSettings);
    var apiMainContent = mainContent.data('jsp');
    apiMainContent.reinitialise();

    $(document).on("click",".click_me", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        // DOESN"T work
        // var myVar = $(this).closest(".target");
        // DOES work
        var myVar = $(".target:first");
        //apiMainContent.scrollToElement(".target");    
        apiMainContent.scrollToElement(myVar);
    });
}

initScrollPane();
```

**Edit:**

It is also my understanding that `closest()` can search `down` the tree which is why I used that particular method per the following link, but perhaps that understanding is incorrect:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5139438/1063287

Answer (score 2):

You use `closest()` wrong way. `closest()` for getting the closest `parents()`. In your case, there's 2 ways to do.

First is:

```
var myVar = $(this).siblings(".target");
```

Second is

```
var myVar = $(this).parent().find('.target');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `closest()` for this, as it works "by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree." ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/))

You need to use `siblings()` ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)) and then search for the nearest one if you have multiple targets. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052013/2610249) for an example how you could do it.